# Random Number Generator without wasting RAM

Tags: randomness

I want to implement RNG on EOS the mainnet. My reference is the [WAX ORNG smart contract](https://github.com/worldwide-asset-exchange/wax-orng)
It is based on the [signidice](https://github.com/gluk256/misc/blob/master/rng4ethereum/signidice.md) which is an Ethereum implementation.

That algorithm is based on an external oracle which signs requests on chain and the signature is the source of randomness, since the private key the oracle uses to sign is private.

To mitigate replay attacks, the signidice requires a table with all previous calls to this function by all users. This requires RAM on EOSIO and I want to remove this requirement.

If I add a nonce to the signing request, making use of eosio::time_point::time_since_epoch() will this make each signing request unique, even if the user tries to use the same input?

copying comments from telegram dev channel:

> @matt_witherspoon: my first thought is that instead of the player
> picking R, the contract uses a monotonic counter (either per player or
> maybe contract-wide). But the oracle would need to be very careful to
> watch for signatures it submits that then get forked out (and to be
> sure trxs it submits have tapos set correctly). Any transactions that
> get forked out would need to the player to resubmit again (to get a
> new R that has never been "revealed" by the oracle).

> @cc32d9: Totally possible. It just needs to hash the transaction ID
> into the result, and stop recording the inputs for uniqueness
> guarantee

> @tbfleming: Maybe also hash the global sequence number of the action
> in case a single transaction needs multiple If the trx id is included,
> then instead of global, the local seq number will work

> @fabian_pinknetwork: you can also add the functionality to change
> signing keys and truncate all signing values after change that was
> planned but never implemented on wax regular rotation would free up
> most of the ram

[image: screenshot of the telegram chat]